# Not able to execute python unit test case

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have 2 class files in the same folder:

> compute_examples.py

```
class Compute:

    def add(self, var1 = 0, var2 = 0):
        return var1 + var2
```

> compute_examples_utc.py

```
from compute_examples import Compute
import unittest
    
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    obj_compute_examples = Compute() 
    
    def test_0_add(self):
        print("Start add test\n")
        
        self.assertEqual(obj_compute_examples.add(2,2),4)
```

I am running the command:

> python -m unittest compute_examples_utc.py

It is giving the following error:

```
Start add test

E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_0_add (compute_examples_utc.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\00_AnI\02_Trainings\01_TestEnv\02_Code\source\compute_examples_utc.py", line 13, in test_0_add
    self.assertEqual(obj_compute_examples.add(2,2),4)
NameError: name 'obj_compute_examples' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: Works For Me™. Could you show where `compute_examples.py` is relative to `compute_examples_utc.py`? Also, try adding `import sys` and `print(sys.path)` to the top of `compute_examples_utc.py`. Those are the places Python will look for libraries.

Comment: @Schwern Thanks for responding. Updated question. Found that the class name was incorrect. On correcting that, the error message has changed.

Comment: You mean `self.obj_compute_examples`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change to:

```py
self.assertEqual(self.obj_compute_examples.add(2, 2), 4)
```

Use `self.obj_compute_examples` to access the property defined in `Test` class.

Unit test result:

```
(venv) ☁  64708057 [master] ⚡  python -m unittest compute_examples_utc.py
Start add test

.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```